# GridView display text rather than foreign key

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, gridview

I have just started to learn how to use the Gridview Control to display SQL data.  I have been able to get almost everything to work except for displaying the more user friendly information for one of my data fields that I populate from a lookup table.   The entire concept of the page I want to be able to Update, Insert and Delete new records too and for some reason I could not get these options to work when I was using the SqlDataSource  so I use LinqDataSource and all is now working (except I haven’t figured out Insert yet…a separate question)

I am also using the controls tabs in Visual Studio to choose and edit the attributes of the controls so kind of using the wizards and not hand coding the example.

What I cannot figure out is how to make my column with employeetypeid that contains the foreign key from the employeetypelookup table to show the employeetype text value for the user so this makes more sense.    I found a “Walkthrough: Displaying a Drop-Down List While Editing in the GridView Web Server Control“   and this works perfectly.   When I go into edit mode the dropdownlist shows the employeetype text and when I choose a different type, the appropriate employeetype id gets stored in the database.

So how can I modify something (the Datasource???) to display the employeetype text in the DataGrid.

```
            <asp:LinqDataSource ID="LinqDataSource1" runat="server" ContextTypeName="SNRmain.SNRmainDataContext" EntityTypeName="" OrderBy="lastname, preferredfirstname" Select="new (personnelid, lastfirstname)" TableName="masterpersonnellastpreferreds"></asp:LinqDataSource>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="LinqDataSource1" DataTextField="lastfirstname" DataValueField="personnelid">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:LinqDataSource ID="LinqDataSource2" runat="server" ContextTypeName="SNRmain.SNRmainDataContext" EnableDelete="True" EnableInsert="True" EnableUpdate="True" EntityTypeName="" TableName="tblappointmentdates" Where="personnelid == @personnelid" OrderBy="startdate desc">
        <WhereParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList1" Name="personnelid" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
        </WhereParameters>
    </asp:LinqDataSource>

    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="snrappointmentid" DataSourceID="LinqDataSource2">
        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="startdate" HeaderText="startdate" SortExpression="startdate" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="endingdate" HeaderText="endingdate" SortExpression="endingdate" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="employeetypeid" SortExpression="employeetypeid">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" DataSourceID="LinqDataSource3" DataTextField="employeetypetext" DataValueField="employeetypeid" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("employeetypeid", "{0}") %>'>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("employeetypeid") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="apptcomment" HeaderText="apptcomment" SortExpression="apptcomment" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="dateentered" HeaderText="dateentered" SortExpression="dateentered" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:LinqDataSource ID="LinqDataSource3" runat="server" ContextTypeName="SNRmain.SNRmainDataContext" EntityTypeName="" OrderBy="employeetypetext" Select="new (employeetypeid, employeetypetext)" TableName="tblemployeetypelookups">
    </asp:LinqDataSource>
```

I have tried to modify  the LinqDataSource2  to include  a statement like the one below but that does not work and I get an error that does not make sense to me.   "System.Web.Query.Dynameic.ParseException: Syntax error.

```
    <asp:LinqDataSource ID="LinqDataSource2" runat="server" ContextTypeName="SNRmain.SNRmainDataContext" EntityTypeName="" Select="snrappointmentid, 
    personnelid, startdate, 
    endingdate, employeetypeid, 
    tblemployeetypelookup.employeetypetext 
    from tblappointmentdates 
    join tblemployeetypelookups on tblappointmentdates.employeetypeid = tblemployeetypelookups.employeetypeid" TableName="tblappointmentdates" Where="personnelid == @personnelid">
        <WhereParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList1" Name="personnelid" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
        </WhereParameters>
    </asp:LinqDataSource>
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you binding `<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("employeetypeid") %>'></asp:Label>` employeetypeid?

Comment: That is used when a user select edit for a row employeetypeid needs to be entered into the database for the update.   I may have not correctly selected this when I was working through the control. But when I do actually use the edit feature the dropdownlist actually shows the text and the correct id is then placed into the database when update is selected.   This was the code that the wizard added.  It seems to be working so I have not modified that.    It's when the user is not in the edit mode that I still want the resulting text to be seen.

Answer (score 0):

Ok if I understood correctly what you should do is to pass the `employeetypeid` in a function and retrieve the text and bind that to control like this.

from

```
 <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("employeetypeid") %>'></asp:Label>
```

to

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<% #GetEmployeeName(Eval("employeetypeid"))%>' runat="server" />
```

so now `GetEmployeeName` is a server function you would write to fetch name from id.

```
protected string GetEmployeeName(int employeetypeid)
{
           //What ever is the way to query and return from here
}
```

Also as side note I noticed you do naming like Label1 which is very poor practice.

Comment: Thanks for helping so far.

I added the code your included with GetEmployeeName that you provided. And developed the function to get the Type Text (you called it 'name').

The first problem I had was that the main file did not like the "Private" of the function so I changed that to "Protected"  and it seemed to at least like that.

Now I am getting an error that are invalid arguments in GetEmployeeName.

        Compiler Error Message: CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'aboutus_who_people_update_master_appointment_gridview.GetEmployeeName(int)' has some invalid arguments